# Why does this AspectJ method signature expression match overwritten methods in subtypes?

Tags: java, aop

I have defined two classes

```
public class A{
    public A myMethod(){
        return this;
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    @Override public B myMethod(){
        return this;
    }
}
```

and the pointcut `execution(public A+ A.*(..))`.

I am surprised that both of the methods get selected by the pointcut. Why is this the case even though I didn't add a plus after the type name of the defining type of `myMethod()`?

If `+` is already there to match subtypes, why the inconsistency in the design of AspectJ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method execution is captured because you are intercepting a method defined in the base class. It will still be matched when overridden in a subclass. The pointcut would **not** match any methods defined in the subclass only.

---

Let me rename your classes to make the code more readable and turn this into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Base class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Base {
  public Base baseAction() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

**Subclass with overridden method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Sub extends Base {
  @Override
  public Sub baseAction() {
    return this;
  }

  public Sub subAction() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Please note that I added another method to the subclass which is not contained in the base class.

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Base().baseAction();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    new Sub().baseAction();
    System.out.println("-----------------");
    new Sub().subAction();
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.app.Base;

public aspect MyAspect {
  before() : execution(Base Base.*(..)) {
    System.out.println("Base Base.*(..)   -> " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : execution(Base+ Base.*(..)) {
    System.out.println("Base+ Base.*(..)  -> " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : execution(Base Base+.*(..)) {
    System.out.println("Base Base+.*(..)  -> " + thisJoinPoint);
  }

  before() : execution(Base+ Base+.*(..)) {
    System.out.println("Base+ Base+.*(..) -> " + thisJoinPoint);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
Base Base.*(..)   -> execution(Base de.scrum_master.app.Base.baseAction())
Base+ Base.*(..)  -> execution(Base de.scrum_master.app.Base.baseAction())
Base Base+.*(..)  -> execution(Base de.scrum_master.app.Base.baseAction())
Base+ Base+.*(..) -> execution(Base de.scrum_master.app.Base.baseAction())
-----------------
Base Base.*(..)   -> execution(Sub de.scrum_master.app.Sub.baseAction())
Base+ Base.*(..)  -> execution(Sub de.scrum_master.app.Sub.baseAction())
Base Base+.*(..)  -> execution(Sub de.scrum_master.app.Sub.baseAction())
Base+ Base+.*(..) -> execution(Sub de.scrum_master.app.Sub.baseAction())
-----------------
Base+ Base+.*(..) -> execution(Sub de.scrum_master.app.Sub.subAction())
```

Can you see how `Sub Sub.subAction()` is only captured if you also add `+` to the class name in the method signature? This is also a nice example of what `+` does and why you need it. You do need `Base+` for both return type and method signature in order to capture `Sub Sub.subAction()`!

Comment: Thanks for the illustration! Maybe I should have posed my question more clearly: Why this inconsistency in the design of AspectJ? Can you give an example of when this behaviour is desirable?

Comment: I am not sure what you see as inconsistent here. Please elaborate.

Comment: The inconsistency is that in other instances we explicitly use the + to also match subtypes. Why handle it different here?

Comment: The answer is simple: OOP. If `Sub extends Base` then each `Sub` instance is also a `Base` and especially each method defined in `Base` also exists for `Sub`, **but** still is originally a `Base` method, no matter if you override it in `Sub` or not. Furthermore, a method **only** defined in `Sub` or an explicit return type `Sub` is a different beast: You can only match it via `Sub` directly or via `Base+` indirectly. I find this quite consistent and trust you will too once you wrap your head around it. :-)

Comment: Turns out I just found an IntelliJ bug - the IDE shows that `execution(Base Base+.*(..))` would not match `BaseAction::sub` when it actually does. I should have seen the difference between my results and your example right away. Anyways, there is no inconsistency. Thanks for your clarification!